# Timezone Error when running GWT/GAE app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm getting this error when running my GWT/GAE app:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to restore the previous TimeZone    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restoreLocalTimeZone(DevAppServerImpl.java:348)  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:251)     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.TimeZone.setDefaultInAppContext(java.util.TimeZone)  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2117)   at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restoreLocalTimeZone(DevAppServerImpl.java:344)  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:251)     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)

Although I added `-Dappengine.user.timezone=UTC` and `-Dappengine.user.timezone.impl=UTC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error got fixed when I updated the GAE version from 1.8.0 to 1.8.8+

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodException error on JDK 8, its likely this bug https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-maven-plugin/issues/54

The solution discussed there is to add config to the appengine maven plugin.

```
                <jvm_flag>
                    <jvm_flag>-Dappengine.user.timezone=UTC</jvm_flag>
                </jvm_flag>
```

Passing the argume as -D does not work (nor adding .impl) as discuess in older solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-05:00"));
```

for example this is for Bogota, Lima, Quito .. you can choose your Zone [here](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml)